Why is there no image when converting MP3 files with 0 seconds to MP4 with FFmpeg?
I'm converting MP3 audios to MP4 files with an image, and all my MP3 audios with 0 seconds come with an MP4 video without an image, I'm using the command below:
u/echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Set the paths
set "audio_dir=C:\Users\rafae\Desktop\Nova pasta (3)"
set "image_file=%audio_dir%\image.png"
set "output_dir=%audio_dir%\Finished"

:: Create output directory if it doesn't exist
if not exist "%output_dir%" mkdir "%output_dir%"

:: Loop over all MP3 files in the audio directory
for %%f in ("%audio_dir%\*.mp3") do (
  set "input_audio=%%f"
  set "output_file=%output_dir%\%%~nxf.mp4"
  echo Processing !input_audio!...

  :: Convert MP3 to MP4 with image
  ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "!image_file!" -i "!input_audio!" -r 1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryslow -crf 12 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -shortest "!output_file!"
)
echo Done!
pause


The issue is not reproducible. Try using the following input image: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=1 -update 1 image_file.png and the following input MP3: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -t 10 input_audio.mp3. Execute the following command: ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image_file.png -i input_audio.mp3 -r 1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryslow -crf 12 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -shortest output_file.mp4. In the script, try adding -y argument for automatic overwriting. What version of FFmpeg are you using?

Thanks for the help, I tested this alternative but it remains the same, would ffmpeg have any problem applying images to videos with 0 seconds? The version of ffmpeg I use is 7.0.2

I tested with ffmpeg-7.0.2-full_build.7z from here in Windows 10. The issue is not reproducible.

Maybe it's a player related issue. Try playing using FFplay: ffplay output_file.mp4

I managed to solve it with the code ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i "!image_file!" -i "!input_audio!" -map 0:v -map 1:a -r 10 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryslow -crf 12 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -shortest "!output_file!" I added to the code 1 -framerate and -map 0:v -map 1:a -r 10

Thank you very much for the help again, I learned some commands that I didn't know
